# Find congruent relation

Tags: matrices

I know this is a well know problem, but I can not find easily the solution.

Given the symmetric positive definite matrices $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, I'm looking for $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $X^{t} A X = B$ (congruence relation).

I know that the solution exist since both matrices are positive definite, but I can not figure out an easy way to compute $X$. Thanks!

G.

Answer (score 1):

Diagonalize $A,B$ using orthogonal transformations:  let $A=P^{-1}DP, B=Q^{-1}EQ$ with $D,E$ diagonal, $P,Q$ orthogonal.  You can do this as they are symmetric.   Because they are orthogonal, $P^{-1}=P^t, Q^{-1}=Q^t$.  Then let $X_{ii}=\sqrt{ \dfrac {E_{ii}}{D_{ii}}}$, all other elements $0$.  This fails if $B$ has more zero eigenvalues than $A$.  Now $B=Q^{-1}X^tPAP^{-1}XQ=(P^tXQ)^tA(P^tXQ)$

Comment: In order to satisfy the congruence relation the matrices A and B must have the same number of negative, zero and positive eigenvalue (i.e. inertial of the matrix).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Ross. Actually I solved the problem more as follow:

Do the Cholesky decomposition of $A$ and $B$ since they are symmetric definite positive, i.e.

$A=W^t W$ and $B=Z^t Z$ where $W$ and $Z$ are invertible matrices.

The equation $X^t A X = B$ become

$W^t W = X^t Z^t Z X = (ZX)^t ZX$

therefore $X = Z^{-1} W$.

Comment: That works, too.  Simpler than mine.